# Android Studio 3.3 Design is Not Showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio-3.3

Design not displaying in Android Studio 3.3

[image: Android Studio 3.3 Design is Not Showing]

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Warning** (i.e., yellow triangle) showing up in **Right Top Corner**. It always contain some resolution to design issue.

Comment: Not Solved Bro...Any Other Idea

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your selected option as shown in image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are finding **Actionbar** and **Theme** view in Layout Manager then in **Android Studio 3.3** Version.

You should checked **Layout Decoration** option 
on left-top side in **View Option**

[image: Select this option for Actionbar View]